# HttpClient on .NET 7 fails on Kerberos authentication

Tags: c#, .net, kerberos

We've upgraded our application from .NET 6 to .NET 7 and now the Kerberos authentication fails. I've created a simple console application to replicate the behavior and built it for both .NET 6 and .NET 7. The .NET 6 application does a successful authentication, but .NET 7 fails with the stacktrace below.

- OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard
- .NET Version: 7
- Application: WPF and
  Console App, same behavior.

```
using System.Configuration;

Console.WriteLine("Beep boop bop... starting application");
HttpClientHandler handler = new()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
};
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => {
    return true;
};

HttpClient client = new(handler);

string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdpUrl"];
Console.WriteLine($"Requesting: {url}");

HttpResponseMessage? response = await client.GetAsync(url);

Console.WriteLine($"Response status code: {response.StatusCode}");
Console.WriteLine($"Response: {response}");

Console.WriteLine("Beep boop bop... signing off");

Console.ReadLine();
```

The stacktrace:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Authentication validation failed with error - InvalidToken. at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

From a Kerberos point of view, this is the normal process:

- Call happens to a URL
- The server replies with met een 401 and WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate header
- Client replies with a kerberos token
- The server does the Kerberos validation and returns a 200 reply with in the body a valid JWT which is the case.

I've omitted the token(s) for privacy reasons and added some X's where other data use to be.
Fiddler results for the Kerberos authentication:

```
HTTP/1.1 401
Server: xxxxxxxx
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 10:13:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 519
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: XX_JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/xx; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Cache-Control: no-store
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: xxxxxx
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 10:13:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1124
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: XX_JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/xx; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate (A TOKEN)
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 10:13:22 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

I was expecting the same behavior in .NET and a successful Kerberos authentication.

Comment: We have the same problem, did you get any success with this issue?

We have downgraded to .NET 6 as a workaround for now as we don't have access to SPNEGO services in our dev-environment.

For future googlers you also created a github issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81595

Comment: For future reference. I also found this thread. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/net-runtime/httpclient-on-net-7-fails-on-kerberos-authentication/m-p/3740703

Answer (score 1):

I also found this to be the case with the SSO implementation in my companies environment when using .Net 7.  At my company it's one of those implementations where you send a kerberized request to an endpoint that returns a cookie for your session that has something like prefix={JWT Token} for the value.

In my case what worked as a workaround was creating my own Negotiate header for the httpclient instead of setting UseDefaultCredentials.  I was lazy about it and used the Kerberos.Net library which includes a wrapper for SSPI that is ridiculously easy.

I'm using powershell 7.3.4 so excuse that the sample code is powershell:

```
$contextReceiver=[kerberos.net.win32.sspicontext]::new("http/authn.web.contoso.com","negotiate")  
$tokenbytes=$contextReceiver.requestToken()
$clientHandler=[system.net.httpclienthandler]::new()
$clienthandler.allowautoredirect=$true
$clienthandler.maxautomaticredirection=3  

$client=[system.net.http.httpclient]::new($clienthandler)
$client.defaultrequestheaders.useragent.parseadd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36")  
$client.defaultrequestheaders.connection.add("Keep-Alive")
$client.defaultrequestheaders.authorization=[system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue]::new("Negotiate",[system.convert]::ToBase64String($tokenbytes))  

$test=Wait-Task $client.getasync($url)
```

Comment: Seems I was in the same boat, migrating from net6 to net8, and this did the trick for me.